# Overwrite __add__ method

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

````
class Clock:


   def __init__(self,hours,minutes):```

   self.hours=hours
   self.minutes=minutes



def Clock(hours,minutes):
        if hours>9 and minutes>9:
            return str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)
        elif hours>9 and minutes<10:
            return str(hours)+":0"+str(minutes)
        elif hours<10 and minutes>9:
            return "0"+str(hours)+":"+str(minutes)
        else:
            return "0"+str(hours)+":"+"0"+str(minutes)

def __add__(self,other):
    ????if Clock.Clock(self.hours,self.minutes)+Clock.Clock(other.hours,other.minutes)????



  t=Clock.Clock(5,6)+Clock.Clock(5,6)
  print(t)
````

now when I print `t` I'm getting 05:0605:06
and I wanted to know how do I overwrite the `__add__` function that when I'm doing `Clock.Clock(self,other)+Clock.Clock(self,other)` it's going to print out `Clock(self,other)+Clock(self,other)`
which is= 10:12 for the input above.

Comment: Currently that doesn't even seem to be inside the class, so that might be a start.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding string which would concatenate instead of actually adding the hour and minute values. You might want to do this instead

```
def __add__(self,other):
    return Clock.Clock(self.hours+other.hours,self.minutes+other.minutes)
```

Assuming the  *hours* and *minutes* property is numeric

Answer (score 1):

```
In [4]: class Clock:
   ...:
   ...:
   ...:    def __init__(self,hours,minutes):
   ...:        self.hours=hours
   ...:        self.minutes=minutes
   ...:
   ...:    def __repr__(self):
   ...:         if self.hours>9 and self.minutes>9:
   ...:             return str(self.hours)+":"+str(self.minutes)
   ...:         elif self.hours>9 and self.minutes<10:
   ...:             return str(self.hours)+":0"+str(self.minutes)
   ...:         elif self.hours<10 and self.minutes>9:
   ...:             return "0"+str(self.hours)+":"+str(self.minutes)
   ...:         else:
   ...:             return "0"+str(self.hours)+":"+"0"+str(self.minutes)
   ...:    def __add__(self, other):
   ...:        self.hours += other.hours
   ...:        self.minutes += other.minutes
   ...:        return Clock(self.hours, self.minutes)


In [5]: Clock(5, 6) + Clock(5,6)
Out[5]: 10:12
```

Comment: It's probably better to create a new instance than to modify the instance and returning the representation from addition.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a few liberties with your code. First the `Clock` method looks like its trying to convert to a string. So instead lets define it as `__str__`. We can also implement the string conversion much more succinctly.

As for the `__add__` method. To be consistent it should return a `Clock` object, not a string.

The other thing that the existing answers have missed, is to account for situations where the total minute value exceeds 59 in which case the excess should be included in the hours value.

To calculate this for minutes, take the modulus (`%`) 60 of total minutes. For hours divide by 60 and round down (or just do integer division). The function `divmod` conveniently does both these things for us in one function call.

```
class Clock:

    def __init__(self, hours, minutes):

        if minutes > 59:
            raise ValueError('invalid value for minutes %d' % minutes)

        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes

    def __str__(self):

        return "%d:%02d" % (self.hours, self.minutes)

    def __add__(self, other):

        extrahours, mins = divmod(self.minutes + other.minutes, 60)
        hours = self.hours + other.hours + extrahours
        return Clock(hours, mins)


t = Clock(5, 6) + Clock(5, 6)
print(t)
```

If we now try

```
t = Clock(5, 20) + Clock(5, 50)
```

It correctly prints `11:10` and not `10:70`.